# Integer sequences in Iterator of Iterators (Java)

Tags: java, iterator, sequence

I'm a beginner in programming and I have such thing as `Iterator<Iterator<Integer>> it`. Each iterator in `it` is a sequence of numbers. Like:

```
Iterator1 - (1, 2, 3)
Iterator2 - (4, 5, 6)
Iterator3 - (7, 8, 9)
```

When viewed from a different angle, `it` is:

```
Iterator<Iterator<Integer> ((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9))
```

I need a method, which will `return` `Iterator<Integer> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)`, like:

```
 Iterator<Integer> convert(Iterator<Iterator<Integer>> it) {
        // How to do it?
 }
```

Size and values of each iterator's number sequence in the `it` may be different.

I know I had to try to do it myself, but I do not even understand what should happen here.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for Guava's [`Iterators.concat`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#concat-java.util.Iterator-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to "pre-walk" the iterators, e.g. by collecting them in a list and then returning an iterator to that list, you can create a `Spliterator` from the `Iterator`, use `StreamSupport` to convert that to a `Stream`, and use `flatMap` to do the same with the inner iterators, then get an iterator for that flattened stream.

```
public static <E> Iterator<E> convert(Iterator<Iterator<E>> iterators) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterators, 0), false)
            .flatMap(it -> StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(it, 0), false))
            .iterator();
}
```

Comment: Great Solution, perfect for cases when you fetch restful data while using pagination

Answer (score 1):

I think someone may be able to provide you with a more efficient way, but you could still aggregate all the data in a `List<Integer>` which iterator you'll return :

```
Iterator<Integer> flatten(Iterator<Iterator<Integer>> it) {
    List<Integer> allIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
    it.forEachRemaining(subIt -> subIt.forEachRemaining(value -> allIntegers.add(value)));
    return allIntegers.iterator();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A less elegant solution (because not using Java-8 lambda) is this:

```
 Iterator<Integer> convert(Iterator<Iterator<Integer>> it) {
     List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
     while (it.hasNext()) {
         Iterator<Integer> it2 = it.next();
         while (it2.hasNext()) {
             list.add(it2.next());
         }
     }
     return list.iterator();
 }
```